# Find sum of column, divide column value, and print to new column using awk

Tags: bash, awk, sum, multiple-columns, division

So my data looks like this:

```
file Gibbs kcal rel pop pop2
RR2.out -1752.142111    -1099486.696073  0.000000 -0.0000 1.0000
RR1.out -1752.141887    -1099486.555511  0.140562 -0.2374 0.7891
RR4.out -1752.140564    -1099485.725315  0.970758 -1.6398 0.1947
RR3.out -1752.140319    -1099485.571575  1.124498 -1.8995 0.1502
RR5.out -1752.138532    -1099484.450215  2.245858 -3.7937 0.0227
RR6.out -1752.138493    -1099484.425742  2.270331 -3.8351 0.0218
```

And I want to find the sum of column 6 then divide each value in column 6 by that sum and print these values in a new column titled "weighted"

Using

```
 echo "weighted" >> allRE7
 awk 'NR==FNR{sum+= $6; next}{printf("%0.4f\n", $6/sum)}' input input >> out
 paste input out >> final
```

Gives me

```
 file Gibbs kcal rel pop pop2   weighted
 RR2.out    -1752.142111    -1099486.696073  0.000000 -0.0000 1.0000    0.0000
 RR1.out    -1752.141887    -1099486.555511  0.140562 -0.2374 0.7891    0.4590
 RR4.out    -1752.140564    -1099485.725315  0.970758 -1.6398 0.1947    0.3622
 RR3.out    -1752.140319    -1099485.571575  1.124498 -1.8995 0.1502    0.0894
 RR5.out    -1752.138532    -1099484.450215  2.245858 -3.7937 0.0227    0.0689
 RR6.out    -1752.138493    -1099484.425742  2.270331 -3.8351 0.0218    0.0104
         0.0100
```

I don't know where the 0.0100 value comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the awk code was printed a weighted result for the header line.  To eliminate that, replace:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{sum+= $6; next}{printf("%0.4f\n", $6/sum)}' input input >> out
```

with:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{sum+= $6; next} FNR>1{printf("%0.4f\n", $6/sum)}' input input >> out
```

The `FNR>1` condition assures that `$6/sum` is only printed for the data lines.

#### Improvement

The `echo` and `paste` commands are not necessary.  Try:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{sum+= $6; next} FNR==1{print $0,"weighted"; next} {printf("%s %0.4f\n",$0,$6/sum)}' input input
file Gibbs kcal rel pop pop2 weighted
RR2.out -1752.142111    -1099486.696073  0.000000 -0.0000 1.0000 0.4590
RR1.out -1752.141887    -1099486.555511  0.140562 -0.2374 0.7891 0.3622
RR4.out -1752.140564    -1099485.725315  0.970758 -1.6398 0.1947 0.0894
RR3.out -1752.140319    -1099485.571575  1.124498 -1.8995 0.1502 0.0689
RR5.out -1752.138532    -1099484.450215  2.245858 -3.7937 0.0227 0.0104
RR6.out -1752.138493    -1099484.425742  2.270331 -3.8351 0.0218 0.0100
```

A variation on the above uses a ternary operator (hat tip: [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton)),:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{sum+= $6; next} {print $0, (FNR>1 ? sprintf("%0.4f",$6/sum) : "weighted")}' input input
file Gibbs kcal rel pop pop2 weighted
RR2.out -1752.142111    -1099486.696073  0.000000 -0.0000 1.0000 0.4590
RR1.out -1752.141887    -1099486.555511  0.140562 -0.2374 0.7891 0.3622
RR4.out -1752.140564    -1099485.725315  0.970758 -1.6398 0.1947 0.0894
RR3.out -1752.140319    -1099485.571575  1.124498 -1.8995 0.1502 0.0689
RR5.out -1752.138532    -1099484.450215  2.245858 -3.7937 0.0227 0.0104
RR6.out -1752.138493    -1099484.425742  2.270331 -3.8351 0.0218 0.0100
```

Comment: Just an alternative to consider: `{print $0, (FNR>1 ? sprintf("%0.4f",$6/sum) : "weighted"}`

Comment: @EdMorton Very good.  I added the version with your version to the answer.

Comment: You could also do `awk -v OFMT='%.04f' 'NR==FNR{sum+=$6; next} {print $0, (FNR>1 ? $6/sum : "weighted")}' file file` - the choices are endless :-)! I personally usually find setting OFMT a bit clunky and too global in scope though if it's just for 1 field.

Answer (score 0):

You are computing the average to the heading line as well.

To omit the heading line your `awk` script should be:

```
awk 'FNR==1{next}NR==FNR{sum+= $6; next}{printf("%0.4f\n", $6/sum)}' input input >> out
paste input out >> final
```

A cleaner `awk` script including  the `paste` command is:

```
awk 'FNR==1{next}NR==FNR{sum+= $6; next}{printf("%s %0.4f\n", $0, $6/sum)}' input input
```